# How to understand BOOL *

Tags: ios

Like in this `NSArray` instance method `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id x, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop),`as I know `BOOL` is a primitive type,How can we declare it as a pointer type? why it's not `BOOL` stop here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're defining `stop` as a *pointer* to a `BOOL`, not as a `BOOL` itself.

It lets you do things like pass-by-reference emulation in C and Obj-C:

```
void changeMe (BOOL *pointerToBool) {
    *pointerToBool = ! (*pointerToBool);  // Dereference the address
                                          // to get at variable.
}
:
BOOL myBool = YES;
changeMe (&myBool);   // Pass its address.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap other non-object types (such as a pointer or a struct) in an NSValue.

Assuming you really mean a BOOL* (pointer):

```
NSValue *boolValue = [NSValue value:pointerToBool withObjCType:@encode(BOOL*)];
BOOL *b = [boolValue pointerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

`BOOL *` is pointer of BOOL var. If use it (a pointer) in function argument you can change value of this pointer if you want. Use pointer in argument as a void function, but you can return one or more value in argument

Answer (score 0):

It will help you knowing that BOOL is a signed char, so it can be treated as a it. It's declared in objc.h: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/objc.h

The declaration:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL; 

#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

BOOL* is pretty much the same as char* , and I'm sure you are more used to see the last.